# Can a large file be hashed down to 32 bytes, and then reconstructed from the hash?

Tags: hash, compression

We can hash a file or data using multihash or SHA-256, but can we retrieve the original data or file from the hash?

Are there any methods to retrieve the original file or data from a hash of it without using IPFS?

Or is there any encryption method which encrypts a 5 MB file and outputs a hash-like content of 32 bytes so that we can retrieve the original file from that 32 byte content?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86105/discussion-on-question-by-anu-davis-can-a-large-file-be-hashed-down-to-32-bytes).

Comment: The POINT of a hash is that it is not reversible.

Comment: Please research the site for similar questions before asking. That should help you avoid those constant duplicate flags.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No, there is no way to compress (or hash or encrypt or whatever) a 5 MB file into a 32 byte hash and then reconstruct the original file just from the hash alone.

This is simply because there are *many* more possible 5 MB files than there are 32 byte hashes.  This means that, whatever hashing or compression or other algorithm you use, it *must* map many different 5 MB files to the same 32 byte hash.  And that means that, given only the 32 byte hash, there is no way you can possibly tell which of those different 5 MB files it was created from.

In fact, the same thing happens already if you hash *33 byte files* into 32 byte hashes, and then try to reconstruct the original files from the hashes.  Since there are 256 times as many 33 byte files as there are 32 byte hashes, that already means that there must be several different files that have the same hash.  With 5 MB files, it's many, many, many times worse yet.

---

So how can something like [IPFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System) work, then?

Basically, it relies on the fact that even the number of possible 32 byte hashes is *really* huge* — much, much larger than the total number of *actual* files (of any length) that humans have ever created, or are ever likely to create.  So, while we know that there must be many possible files that have the same 32 byte hash, the chance of actually finding two different files that just happen to have the same hash by chance is still so incredibly small that we can basically assume it will never happen.

(Also, cryptographic hash functions like SHA-256 are designed so that, hopefully, there are no practical ways to deliberately find files with the same hash more efficiently than by just hashing lots of files and hoping against all odds for a random collision.)

This means that if we have some kind of a (possibly distributed) database containing a bunch of files and their SHA-256 hashes, then we can be *pretty* sure that it will never actually contain two files with the same hash, even if that's theoretically possible.

Thus, as long as we have access to such a database, we can use the hash of *any file in the database* to look it up, and be *almost* 100% certain that we will only get one matching file back, not two or more.  Technically, the probability of getting multiple matches is not quite exactly zero, but it's so incredibly small that it can be safely neglected in practice.

---

<sup>*) In fact, it's 2<sup>8×32</sup> = 115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,665,640,564,039,457,584,007,913,129,639,936.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86079/discussion-on-answer-by-ilmari-karonen-can-a-large-file-be-hashed-down-to-32-byt).

Comment: Your first paragraph is technically incorrect. It is entirely possible to compress a 5MB file into 32 bytes. It just isn't possible to generalise it to *all* 5MB files (e.g. my algorithm can be `If(text == completeWorksOfShakespeare) return stringThatIs32Bytes; else return text;`)

Comment: @JBentley: I'm pretty sure the complete works of Shakespeare, even as plain text, would take up a lot more than 5 MiB.

Comment: @Sean However, an ASCII file containing the entirety of Shakespear's works with some extra textual data in the preamble comes in at 5458199 bytes. :-)

Comment: @oakad: Source?

Comment: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt - this has slightly more bytes than the original revision (because of all the copyright nonsense), but it's still pretty close to 5 MiB in size.

Comment: @JBentley I joined this SE because this was my first thought, too. _Hashing_ is not the right technique, but you can _compress_ any arbitrary file down to even zero Bytes. The decompressor just has to work like `if (input == "") return textOf("Lord Of The Rings");` However, I doubt its usefulness.

Comment: @JBentley under your compression scheme, both `stringThatIs32Bytes` and `completeWorksOfShakespeare` compress to `stringThatIs32Bytes`

Comment: Any useful definition of (lossless) compression needs two functions `compress` and `decompress` such that `decompress(compress(foo)) == foo` for *any* `foo`; the precludes having `foo` as part of the definition of `decompress`, which would be a requirement for decompressing a 32-byte value back to the complete works of Shakespeare.

Comment: @JBentley's comment is interesting, but it may be most helpful to think of it as a misleading edge case fact for beginners.  For now, don't get the idea that's a general realistic compression ratio, because it's not.  Then bookmark this for later when you feel like understanding more: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Compression/Dictionary_compression

Comment: @whitneyland On the contrary, it isn't an edge case. The ratio in my example is deliberately extreme in order to highlight the principle, but in fact all compression algorithms work on this principle. They aim to compress inputs that have higher probability of occurring, at the expense of increasing the size of less common inputs. The better the algorithm, the better it will achieve this result.

Comment: @JBentley I agree from that pov, that's why I thought it important to not dismiss your comment and link to a fuller explanation.  I see it as an edge case from the point of view of someone at a level of knowledge that would ask this question. The hope being they could first grok that you don't get those ratios in typical applied scenarios, and then start to understand your comment better as they developer a deeper understanding.

Comment: @OrangeDog this is easily remedied by having `stringThatIs32Bytes` instead "compress" e.g. to `completeWorksOfShakespeare`.

Comment: Pah, my algorithm requires only a monkey and a keyboard. However, the monkey-selection algorithm takes some time...

Answer (score 19):

No, it's not possible to retrieve the original input of a hash, because the input of a hash can be of almost any size ([less than 2'091'752 terabytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17388220/6853079)).

But the hash value is always a fixed length, i.e. a SHA-256 has always a 256-bit value. That's why there are multiple inputs that have the same hashed value, see [Pigeonhole-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

That's also the reason for why you can never retrieve the original input, because you can never be sure that this really would be the original input and not some other input that happens to have the same hash-value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any encryption method which encrypts a 5mb file and outputs a hash like content or 32 bytes content so that we can retrieve the file from that 32 byte content?

Comment: No. Like Maeher already said: it is impossible. You can see this by applying the pidgeon hole principle: you have $2^{32}$ possible hashes/encryption/encodings/pumpernickles, but many *many* more possible plaintexts. It would imply that most encryptions have multiple decryptions, just like this answer explains.

Comment: Specific hashes may limit the message length, but it's not *that* hard to write a padding scheme which can cope with an arbitrary message length.

Comment: Small note: it is certainly possible to guess the input if enough is known about the input file. It's easy to distinguish between two known 5 MB files if most / all data of the files is known or can be guessed.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are correct, there is no way to recover data from a hash.

From your phrasing, I think that this may be an instance of an X-Y problem: you *need* very aggressive lossless compression, and hashes plus some way to undo them *are the closest thing you know of*.

Accordingly you might look into an abuse of [fractal compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_compression): oversample your bitstream such that fractal compression gives an image that results in the original bitstream after a downsampling pass. In principle this can trade the length of your transmitted message for potentially large amounts of pre- and post-computation - you only have to transmit the coefficients and stopping conditions of your fractal calculation and the program that understands them, which could be as small as a few kilobytes, but the search to find those numbers is computationally hard.

Comment: Isn't it lossy though? You'd loose a little entropy every time stuff is compressed.

Comment: I have only imagined this, not proven it correct. In principle the oversampling accounts for the lossiness with extra redundancy. In practice I don't know how well or even if it works, I'm no information theorist.

Comment: @cakins plus one to your comment for an interesting thought experiment, totally appropriate I think to inspire new thoughts and understanding. however it might be helpful to edit in a note  that's it's conjecture.

Answer (score 5):

Simple information theory shows that this is not possible.  For any given hash value, there's an *infinite* number of files that produce that hash (assuming there's no arbitrary limit on the input length).  It's possible(*) to produce **a** file that produces the same hash, but because information has been discarded, there's no way to say whether or not it's **the** file that was originally hashed - all of those infinitely many inputs are equally plausible.

---

(*) "possible" in a theoretical sense - the role of a good cryptographic hash is to make such reconstruction **hard** - preferably as hard as randomly guessing until a match is found.  More rigorously, we say that it should be *computationally infeasible* for an attacker to create a matching input.

Comment: For completeness i would just note that it's only theoretically impossible when you assume a certain context and problem space, and your context is appropriate given the topic of cryptography.  However since the answers and comments seem to veer well into practical data compression issues, others should note it's not theoretically impossible for other applications if your context doesn't rule out massive dictionaries (see my comment above in Illmari's answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a suitably small and finite set of files, that just coincidentally have unique hashes, then yes you can *derive* the file from the hash, using the hash as a *key*.

To guarantee that hash collisions do not occur for your "library" of files, you can reserve a "scratch area" (a gap somewhere) for tie breaking purposes and populate it with arbitrary values that produce a new, unique key for the whole file, which has now changed.

It is probably easier just to use a synthetic key from the outset a la Library of Congress or ISBN.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get back the information from the hash. However there is a method where data can be converted into base64 string. Maybe you are confusing that with hash ?

Comment: Base64 convertion is just another form of plaintext, the question asked for a method hash-reversion.