# How to generate a unique numerical value for an alpha-numeric string?

Tags: encryption, hash

I need to create a unique numerical value for every alpha-numeric string input. Size of output numerical value can be of any size like 32, 64 128 bits. The input string will always be a mongoID type if that helps.
Is there any hashing algorithm available for such purpose.

Comment: What's wrong with SHA-whatever?

Comment: it'll generate an alpha-numeric output, I need a numeric value.

Comment: A bitstring can be interpreted as an integer in a natural way.

Comment: See also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64194/can-a-large-file-be-hashed-down-to-32-bytes-and-then-reconstructed-from-the-has and its duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't limit the length, there are infinitely many alphanumeric strings. The number of even 128-bit numbers is finite, so there's no way to assign a unique 128-bit number to every possible string.

That said, if you don't mind a *very* small risk of collisions, a [cryptographic hash function](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) like [SHA-2](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) or [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) truncated to your desired output length should be fine, as long as that output length is sufficiently large.  With e.g. a 128-bit output size, the average number of strings you'd need to hash before observing even a single collision is around $2^{64}$, probably far more than your software will ever see.  If you're *really* feeling paranoid, bump the length up to 256 bits.

(A point I should probably clarify is that hash functions like SHA-2 and SHA-3 output a fixed-length block of bits.  While this output is often represented in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) for convenience, it's really just a large binary number and could just as well be displayed in any other base, e.g. in the plain old decimal system we humans like to use.)